# retriving the data from sqlserver receive the format was money and date is displayed decimal values

Tags: android, android-layout

list view the amount was displayed .0000 and date is .00.00.00 if i want money is 23989 and date is 21-10-2015[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uZovj.png)
code is:

```
public class Totalamount extends Activity {
    ConnectionClass connectionClass;



ProgressBar pbbar;
ListView lstpro;
SearchView serview;

String z = "";
String proid;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_custdeta);

    connectionClass=new ConnectionClass();
   // customer=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edtcustomer);
    serview=(SearchView)findViewById(R.id.searchview);
    pbbar=(ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.pbbar);
    pbbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    lstpro=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.lstproducts);
    proid="";
    FillList fillList=new FillList();
    fillList.execute("");
    }
public class FillList extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    List<Map<String, String>> prolist  = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {

    pbbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
@TargetApi(11)
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String r) {

    pbbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    Toast.makeText(Totalamount.this, r, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    String[] from = { "A", "B" };
    int[] views = { R.id.lblproid, R.id.lblproname };
    final SimpleAdapter ADA = new SimpleAdapter(Totalamount.this,
            prolist, R.layout.activity_totalamount, from,
            views);

    lstpro.setAdapter(ADA);






    lstpro.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                                int arg2, long arg3,int position) {
            HashMap<String, Object> obj = (HashMap<String, Object>) ADA
                    .getItem(arg2);

            proid = (String) obj.get("A");
            String proname = (String) obj.get("B");




        }

     @Override
     public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
           int position, long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
           Intent newActivity = new Intent(Totalamount.this,
                 CityBiker.class);
           startActivity(newActivity);
           break;



        }
     }

    });

  try {
      serview.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
          @Override
          public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String text) {
              return false;
          }

          @Override
          public boolean onQueryTextChange(String text) {
              ADA.getFilter().filter(text);


              return false;

          }
      });
  }catch (Exception ex)
  {
      z = "Error retrieving data from table";
}
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

    try {
        Connection con = connectionClass.CONN();
        if (con == null) {
            z = "Error in connection with SQL server";
        } else {
            String query = "SELECT Date,sum(TotalAmount) as AMD FROM tmEstimate group by Date order by Date  ";
            PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(query);
            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
           // Year,No,Date,mCustomer.Name as Customer,TotalAmount
            ArrayList<String> data1 = new ArrayList<String>();
            while (rs.next()) {
                Map<String, String> datanum = new HashMap<String, String>();
                datanum.put("A", rs.getString("Date"));
                datanum.put("B", rs.getString("AMD"));
                //datanum.put("C", rs.getString("AMD"));
                prolist.add(datanum);
            }


            z = "Success";
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        z = "Error retrieving data from table";

    }
    return z;
}
}
}
```

Comment: Please format your question, it is impossible to understand anything. Also add some details, I cannot understand what are you asking about

Comment: Database Column :Amount  256, Fetch the Listview  show as 256.0000